# Repeating a video on loop using OpenCV and Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, video

I am trying to create a simple program that will play a video using OpenCV on repeat until the waitKey is pressed. The video will play once and then give an error message "(-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'". I was getting this message earlier but fixed it by changing the file location. I'm almost positive that the issue comes from the fact that when the video ends the next frame is nonexistent so it cant be read, as breaking the while loop when the frame is None doesn't give an error. Every solution I have tried has failed. Any help?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video_file_location')


while True:

     _, frame = cap.read()

     cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
     if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
         break



cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting the `cv2.VideoCapture()` into the loop and the frame should only show when the return is `True`  and that is your problem in your code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 




while True:
    #This is to check whether to break the first loop
    isclosed=0
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture('videoplayback.mp4')
    while (True):

        ret, frame = cap.read()
        # It should only show the frame when the ret is true
        if ret == True:

            cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
                # When esc is pressed isclosed is 1
                isclosed=1
                break
        else:
            break
    # To break the loop if it is closed manually
    if isclosed:
        break



cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

In Case you want to play video in fullscreen loop mode.

```
import cv2
widow_name="window"
videoFileName="video.mp4"
#Loop for playing video in repeat model
while True:
    isClose=False
    video=cv2.VideoCapture(videoFileName)
    #Set Video Frame to Full Screen
    cv2.namedWindow(widow_name, cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)
    cv2.setWindowProperty(widow_name, cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
    #Loop for Reading Video Frame
    while(True):
       ret, frame=video.read()   
       if(ret==True):
           cv2.imshow(widow_name,frame)
           #Esc button(27) to exit the video
           if(cv2.waitKey(1)==27):
               isClose=True
               break
       else:
           break
    #Close Repeat Video Loop
    if(isClose):
        break
# Release video and destory frame after ESC press
video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```